# Filter data after successfully log in

Tags: postgresql, authentication, sequelize.js

I am still learning, so i am not sure if my design is the best approach. I having a hard time connecting the pieces.

So, i am trying to build a simple app (using node, express, react and postgreSQL/sequelize) that a user can log in and see/create/update his books. With that in mind i created two postgress tables (user and catalogs). User table will manage the login/register and catalog will store all data about the books of all users.

I'm having a hard time organizing the flow in my mind.

1. Should table catalogs belongsTo user?
2. After the user successfully log in, how can i show only his entries and not other users? (I've tried to find info, but all tutorials teach up till authentication part)

Comment: To your first question: Yes. What you describe is a 1:M relationship between Users:Catalogs. You create this be by adding the `user_id` (assumed column name) to the `catalogs` table and creating a FK. As to the second question: Join the tables on `user_id` and use `where current_user =` *what user signs in with* (name or id) .  That ensures a user can only see their catalogs. NOTE: do **not** use table name *user* it is both a Postgres and SQL standard reserved word.

Comment: hey @Belayer! Tks for response! So, in my /login route, after doing the verifications, if i want to send the queried data as response to frontend call and then redirect the user to /catalog, for example, should my route res.write(data_queried) and then res.redirect(/catalog)?